# joomla! 2.5 and Semantic Grid

Tags: css, joomla, grid, less

I hope you had a good weekend.

I have a question for you.

I use joomla! 2.5 and Semantic Grid (that use less).

In my header I call things like in the SG examples :

```
<link media="screen" type="text/less" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/css/styles.less" rel="stylesheet">
// my less file
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/js/less-1.1.3.min.js">
// the js less compiler I think
```

When I take a look at the network panel in firebug there are 404 CSS files.
But that's the second time they load. See.

```
GET /joomla/ 200 OK
GET fixed.less 304 Not Modified
GET less-1.1.3.min.js 304 Not Modified
GET reset.css 304 Not Modified
GET demo.css 304 Not Modified
GET grid.less 200 OK
GET fixed.less 304 Not Modified
GET grid.less 304 Not Modified
GET reset.css 404 Not Found // http://localhost/joomla/stylesheets/reset.css
GET demo.css 404 Not Found // http://localhost/joomla/stylesheets/demo.css
```

It reloads my @import but with a wrong path to the files.

```
http://localhost/joomla/stylesheets/demo.css
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/joomla/templates/myTpl/css/stylesheets/demo.css
```

And so styles doesnt display.

In my `styles.less` I do my import this way: `@import 'stylesheets/demo.css';`

What is causing this problem, and how can I avoid it ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're not calling the file from the correct location

Try using `@import '../stylesheets/demo.css';`

On a side note, you have forgotten to add semi-colons inside the PHP tags like so:

```
<link media="screen" type="text/less" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/styles.less" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/less-1.1.3.min.js">
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the semi-colons ^^. Well I tried changing the path but it's not working, as you can see upper the first time the 'bad' files are called they are 200 or 304 so OK. I don't understand why they are called a second time, and even less why their path mysteriously became wrong.

Comment: and what happens if you use `@import 'templates/myTpl/css/stylesheets/demo.css';` ?

Comment: OH WAW ! I changed their path to the fully one. "/joomlafolder/templates/myTpl/css/demo.css and reset.css and it works ! But... if I change the name of my joolma folder it'll not work anymore. Any idea ?! (but you were right it's a path problem thx). Edit : no, just templates/blabla doesn't work

Comment: glad you got it working. be sure to change the path when you put the site on a live server ;)